# How to make another project in Angular in the current project

Tags: angular

How to make another project in Angular in the current project? Currently I am working in a project. In the same project I have to create another project for a different client.

How to do this for both projects with same `node_module` and same package.

Comment: https://angular.io/cli/generate#application-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just generate a new one:

```
ng g application <your_app>
```

This will automatically add it in your angular.json

```
"projects": {
   "your_app": {...}
   "another_app": {...}
}
```

and then just serve it with

```
ng s <your_app>
```